# В чем ошибка C++ код

Tags: c++

Задание - В цикле с предусловием пользователем вводятся числа до тех пор,
пока их сумма не превысит 100. Определить количество введенных четных и
нечетных чисел

```
#include stdio.h
#include conio.h
#include math.h
#include Windows.h
#include iostream
using namespace std;

void main()
{

    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    float x, kn, kc, summa;
    summa = 0;
    kc = 0;
    kn = 0;



    do 
    {
        printf("%s", "Vvedite chislo x: ");
        scanf("%f", &x);
        summa = x + summa;
    } while (summa < 100);
    if (x % 10 % 20 == 0)
        ++kc;
    else ++kn;
    x /= 10;
}
cout << "Kol-vo 4etnix cifr:" << kc < endl
     << "Kol-vo ne4etnix cift:" << kn << endl;
}
```

Comment: И где же тут **ПРЕД**условие?

Comment: Ну, начнём хотя бы с того, что цикла с **пред**условием у вас в программе нет...

Comment: Так **чисел** или **цифр**? И еще - а зачем вам игры с `ConsoleCP` при работе с латинскими буквами? :)

Comment: Помогите предусловие написать

Comment: код подсчета чет/нечет лучше все таки внутрь цикла внести. Ну и написать его правильно.

Comment: Предусловие организуется использованием WHILE () {}. В то время как DO {} WHILE () работает по пост-условию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int x, sum = 0;
    unsigned int even_n = 0, even_d = 0, odd_n = 0, odd_d = 0;
    while(sum <= 100)
    {
        cout << "Enter integer number: ";
        cin >> x;
        sum += x;
        if (x%2) odd_n++; else even_n++;
        while(x)
        {
            if (x%2) odd_d++; else even_d++;
            x /= 10;
        }
    }
    cout << "Even numbers: " << even_n << endl;
    cout << "Odd  numbers: " << odd_n << endl;
    cout << "Even digits: " << even_d << endl;
    cout << "Odd  digits: " << odd_d << endl;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Ну, если ответ устроил - помечайте как принятый, и дело с концом...

Comment: и еще вопросик , что означает even_d и odd_d

Comment: Четные и нечетные **цифры**. Вы же так и не пояснили, нужно количество **чисел** или **цифр**...

Comment: Уже второй ответ @Harry с решением задачи на который я натыкаюсь.

Comment: @ИльяЧижанов У меня ощущение, что вас устроит только ответ, когда человек задаст вопрос и сам напишет ответ :) Все остальное вы будете считать недостойным SO :) Вобщем, ваша позиция мне понятна, мое дело - помогать людям, где я считаю это возможным, ваше дело - минусовать за эту помощь :)

Comment: Вы правы. Это ваше дело. Правила не запрещают ни задавать такие вопросы, ни отвечать. А моё дело минусовать то что мне не нравится. "задаст вопрос и сам напишет ответ" - мне это показалось выпадом в сторону моих вопросов по bison но если бы мой вопрос был лёгким то мне бы не пришлось самому на него отвечать оставив ответ на этот вопрос для будущих поколений.